# Laravel array index variable won't pass to redirected view

Tags: php, sql, laravel

My $data['orders'] won't pass to my redirected view and i get the error "Undefined index: orders (View: /.../pages/userhome.blade.php)". For some reason the $data['user'] variable will pass and show its value but the 'orders' one will not. Ive changed the name and why way i create the data array but its still won't work.

pagescontroller.php

```
        $this->validate($request, []);
        $data = array();
        $orderdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $data['user'] = Auth::user();
        $ordernum = Str::uuid()->toString();
        $sum = 0;

        $cart = DB::table('cart')->where('buyerid', '=', auth()->user()->id)->paginate(10);

        foreach ($cart as $item) {

            $product = Product::find($item->itemid);
            $orderitem = new Orderitem;
            $orderitem->buyerid = $item->buyerid;
            $orderitem->productid = $product->id;
            $orderitem->quantity = $item->quantity;
            $orderitem->ordernumber = $ordernum;
            $orderitem->dateordered = $orderdate;
            $sum = $sum + (number_format($product->price * $item->quantity, 2));
            $product->sold = $product->sold + $item->quantity;
            $orderitem->save();
        }

        $order = new Order;
        $order->buyerid = Auth::user()->id;
        $order->customeremail = Auth::user()->email;
        $order->customeraddress = ''; //$request->input('address');
        $order->total = number_format($product->price * $item->quantity, 2);
        $order->dateordered = $orderdate;
        $order->city = ''; //$request->input('city');
        $order->zipcode = ''; //$request->input('zipcode');
        $order->ordernumber = $ordernum;
        $order->total = $sum;
        $order->save();

        $orders = DB::table('orders')->where('buyerid', '=', auth()->user()->id)->get();
        $data['orders'] = $orders;

        return redirect("/userhome/{$data['user']->name}")->with('success', 'Your order has been sent. A confirmation will be sent to your email shortly.')->with(compact($data));
```

userhome.blade.php
the code fails right at the '@if(count($data['orders']) > 0)' line

```
<h1>{{ $data['user']->name }}</h1>

    <section class="topsellers">
        <h2>Orders</h2>
        <div class="container flex">

            @if (count($data['orders']) > 0)
                @foreach ($data['orders'] as $order)

                    <div class="productcard" }>
                        <p>test</p>

                    </div>

                @endforeach

            @else
                <p>Looks like you have no current orders.</p>

            @endif

        </div>
        {{-- {{$data['products']->links()}} --}}
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your controller method to get the orders

First: change your `redirect` like below:

```
return redirect("/userhome/{$data['user']->name}")
->with('success', 'Your order has been sent. A confirmation will be sent to your email shortly.');
```

Second : Query from your orders table in controller method then pass to the view like below code;

```
public function someMethod()
{
   $data['orders'] = DB::table('orders')->where('buyerid', '=', auth()->user()->id)->get();
   return view('userhome', $data);
}
```